# python list.pop() modifies original list (not just copy)

Tags: python

Situation: After making a copy of the original list I use pop to modify said copy. As it turns out, the original list gets affected by the change.

I even after checking the original list and the copy are not the same object, poping an element of the copy will will pop the same element in the original.

See below for an example of the script. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
l = [['1412898', 'Jack', 'headache med', '8ET-500'],
     ['1423859', 'Sonny', 'prostate med', '8ET-800'],
     ['1413836', 'Paco', 'headache med', '8ET-500']]

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.fp_rows= info

    def sortbyauditor(self):
        self.fp_rows_copy = self.fp_rows[:]

        print self.fp_rows is self.fp_rows_copy
        for i in self.fp_rows_copy:
            i.pop(1)
        print self.fp_rows_copy
        print self.fp_rows

app= App(l)
app.sortbyauditor()
```

Comment: Please, refrain from down voting. I have searched for hours and I never got a relevant answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`some_list[:]` is only a shallow copy. You seem to need a deep copy

```
from copy import deepcopy

copy = deepcopy(some_list)
```

**Edit**

To understand why "one objects affects the other" take a look at the `id` of each list:

```
original = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
shallow = original[:]
deep = deepcopy(original)

print([id(l) for l in original])
# [2122937089096, 2122937087880]

print([id(l) for l in shallow])
# [2122937089096, 2122937087880]

print([id(l) for l in deep])
# [2122937088968, 2122937089672]
```

You can see that the `id`s of the lists in `original` are the same as the `id`s in `shallow`. That means the nested lists are the exact same objects. When you modify one nested list the changes are also in the other list.

The `id`s for `deep` are different. That are just copies. Changing them does not affect the original list.

Comment: This works, thanks. I've never heard of deep/shallow copies. However, I still don't know how one object affects the other.

Comment: Thanks. I see now what goes on. When I started learning (from several books) it was never mentioned the shallow copy/deep copy situation.  They mention things like: a= 5 ... b=a ... a=3 ... b->still 5 and a is now 3.  Anyway, deep copy works. But I also see the power of immutable objects like tuples.