# Unexpected change of list value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why is this list `r` getting altered even if I am only trying to make changes in list `v`? Even though they do not point to same memory location.

```
r = v = list()
r = [[2,2,1],[2,8,3],[10,2,1],[8,4,2],[4,6,4]]
for c, a in enumerate(r):
    if len(v) > 0:
        v[0][0]=c
        v[0][1]=c
    v.append(a)
print('r',r)
print('v',v)
print(hex(id(r)))
print(hex(id(v)))
```

Comment: can you properly format this?

Comment: You put references to `r`'s sublists into `v` and then change them. Since r and v share the same sublists, changing one changes the other. If you don't want that, try `v.append(a[:])` to make a copy of the sublist.

Comment: Tons of similar questions like yours, such ad [python list.pop() modifies original list (not just copy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120380/python-list-pop-modifies-original-list-not-just-copy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does foo.append(bar) affect all elements in a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360286/why-does-foo-appendbar-affect-all-elements-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 lines to your code and see the output.

```
print(hex(id(r[0])))
print(hex(id(v[0])))
```

The output I got is -

```
('r', [[4, 4, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]])
('v', [[4, 4, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]])
id(r) 0x39ccb48L
id(v) 0x17626c8L
id(r[0]) 0x39cc7c8L
id(r[0]) 0x39cc7c8L
```

Although 'r' and 'v' are different, r[0] and v[0] point to the same object. Hence, modifying v[0] also modifies r[0].

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
>>> id(r) == id(v)
True
```

Substitute `r,v=[],[]`

```
>>> id(r) == id(v)
False
```

It is better to place the condition code after the variable is defined (Add to line 2)

Answer (score 0):

`v.append(a)` adds a reference to `r`'s sublists to `v`. `r` and `v` are different, but their contained items are the same. Expand your prints to include the sublists and you'll see

```
r = v = list()
r = [[2,2,1],[2,8,3],[10,2,1],[8,4,2],[4,6,4]]
for c, a in enumerate(r):
    if len(v) > 0:
        v[0][0]=c
        v[0][1]=c
    v.append(a)
print('r',r)
print('v',v)
print(hex(id(r)),[hex(id(i)) for i in r])
print(hex(id(v)),[hex(id(i)) for i in v])
```

I get

```
r [[4, 4, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]]
v [[4, 4, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]]
0x7f7f0d4e8848 ['0x7f7f0d55ff88', '0x7f7f0d55ffc8', '0x7f7f0d38c708', '0x7f7f0d38c648', '0x7f7f0d3a0ac8']
0x7f7f0d3a0c48 ['0x7f7f0d55ff88', '0x7f7f0d55ffc8', '0x7f7f0d38c708', '0x7f7f0d38c648', '0x7f7f0d3a0ac8']
```

If you want the lists to be independent, copy the sublists. All I did was change `v.append(...)` (and removed the initial assignment to `r` which was unneeded)

```
v = list()
r = [[2,2,1],[2,8,3],[10,2,1],[8,4,2],[4,6,4]]
for c, a in enumerate(r):
    if len(v) > 0:
        v[0][0]=c
        v[0][1]=c
    v.append(a[:])
print('r',r)
print('v',v)
print(hex(id(r)),[hex(id(i)) for i in r])
print(hex(id(v)),[hex(id(i)) for i in v])
```

Which gives

```
r [[2, 2, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]]
v [[4, 4, 1], [2, 8, 3], [10, 2, 1], [8, 4, 2], [4, 6, 4]]
0x7fa258a91848 ['0x7fa258b08f88', '0x7fa258b08fc8', '0x7fa258935748', '0x7fa258935688', '0x7fa258949b08']
0x7fa258949c88 ['0x7fa2589357c8', '0x7fa258a915c8', '0x7fa258949d08', '0x7fa258949d88', '0x7fa258949dc8']
```