# Assigning values to list of lists changes member list

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I would like to know why a is not changed in the code below, but f is changed.

After assigning 5 to c[0], a remains 2 and c[0] changes from 2 to 5. This makes sense to me because I did not assign a value to a.
After assigning 8 to t[0][0], f[0] is changed from 1 to 8. This does not make sense to me, because I am changing t not f.

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = [a,b]

print(c)
print(a)

c[0]= 5

print(c)
print(a)


f = [1,1,1]
s = [2,2,2]
t = [f,s]

print(t)
print(f)

t[0][0] = 8

print(t)
print(f)

output:

[2, 3]
2
[5, 3]
2
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
[1, 1, 1]
[[8, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
[8, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Because you **never mutated the int** inside the list (indeed, int objects are immutable so there is no direct way to do that unless you are willing to hack the runtime internals) and in the other case, you **do** mutate the list inside the list. Read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You'll see the same thing if you do `t[0] = [8, 1, 1]`.

Comment: "This does not make sense to me, because I am changing t not f." No, you are **not changing `t`**. You are changing an object that `t` contains, which happens to be referenced by `f`, so you have it backwards

Comment: watch this video by ned bachelder and you'll understand all of this. https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns (start at 3:40 or so if you're impatient)

Comment: This is your question. There are many like it, but this one is yours. Probably still a good idea to look at the others though, because it's all the same problem: `t` is referring to `f` and `s`, not a copy of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326624/unexpected-change-of-list-value

Comment: This might help: http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: The video by acushner cleared things up.  I now understand the difference between mutable and immutable objects in python. After reading the responses, I learned about the difference.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that `lists` are treated by `reference` in `python`, what this means is that when you write this:

```py
f = [1,1,1]
s = [2,2,2]
t = [f,s]
```

`t[0]` is pointing to the `list f` and `f[0]` is pointing to the value `1` in other words when you change `t[0][0] = 8` in someway you are saying `f[0] = 8`.

Below is how it should look the memory before and after the assignation of `t[0][0] = 8`

[image of how should lool the memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x3g5.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x3g5.png)

Comment: It is important to understand, this is nothing unique to lists, all objects work this way, including ints

Comment: all objects are treated by reference in python  I Hope the above helps!

Comment: All objects are treated “by reference”, you simply can’t *mutate* ints.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a default aliasing property with assigning objects. we can verify this using "is" operator.

is "a" and "b" are two different list "is" operation will return a False.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
print(a==b)
True
print(a is b)
False
```

if "a" is assigned to "c" , on doing "is" operation will receive a True. means both objects are same, or poiting to same memory.

assign a to c

```
c = a
print(a == c)
True
print(a is c)
True
```

a and c are pointing to same object, changes on one list will get updated on other object also

```
a[0]=5
print(a)
[5, 2, 3]
print(c)
[5, 2, 3]
```

we can do a explicit copy or cloning of existing list.

cloning using slicing

```
d=a[:]
print(a==d)
True
print(a is d)
False

d[0] = 6
print(d)
[6, 2, 3]
print(a)
[5, 2, 3]
```

Please try below code.

```
f = [1,1,1]
s = [2,2,2]
t = [f[:],s[:]]
print(t)
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
t[0][0] = 8
print(t)
[[8, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
print(f)
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: “Default aliasing for memory optimization” is an… odd way of describing it. You’re simply assigning yet another name to the object. There’s only one object until and unless you explicitly copy it. Not because memory, but because you explicitly created only one object and never copied it.

Comment: thanks, updated content